How to transform and pivot a rather messy table in R using tidyverse?
I have a table with approximately 2000 entries that contains names, positions, field of expertise, and addresses of professors. The table is quite messy, and I’m struggling to find a programmatic way to transform and pivot it into a tidy format.
My goal is to create a tidy table that includes at least the following columns: names, positions, field of expertise, and email address.
(one recurring pattern throughout the data is that each person is separated by a NA from the next one.)

Here is a sample of the data:



data
field




Person 1, MD
A


Associate Professor of A
A


Program Associate, A
A


Senior Medical Director, FGP Operations
A


UMMG Ambulatory Surgery
A


Residency Program
A


Core Educational Lead
A


Email1@email.edu
A


NA
A


Person 2, MD
B


Person 2
B


Clinical Assistant Professor of B
B


Medical Student Clerkship and Core Educational Lead
B


Email2@email.edu
B


NA
B


labcoat
B


Person 3, MD
B


Clinical Assistant Professor of B
B


Email3@email.edu
B


NA
B


labcoat
B


Person 4, MD
B


Professor of B
B


Professor of B
B


Email4@email.edu
B


NA
B


Person 5, MD
C


Person 5
C


Professor of C
C


Professor of C
C


Associate Chair, Quality
C


Department of Urology and Service Chief
C


Email5@email.edu
C


132-547-1321
C


NA
C



Here is the tibble code (to reproduce):
tibble::tribble(
                                                  ~data, ~field,
                                         "Person 1, MD",    "A",
                             "Associate Professor of A",    "A",
                                 "Program Associate, A",    "A",
              "Senior Medical Director, FGP Operations",    "A",
                              "UMMG Ambulatory Surgery",    "A",
                                    "Residency Program",    "A",
                                "Core Educational Lead",    "A",
                                     "Email1@email.edu",    "A",
                                                     NA,    "A",
                                         "Person 2, MD",    "B",
                                             "Person 2",    "B",
                    "Clinical Assistant Professor of B",    "B",
  "Medical Student Clerkship and Core Educational Lead",    "B",
                                     "Email2@email.edu",    "B",
                                                     NA,    "B",
                                              "labcoat",    "B",
                                         "Person 3, MD",    "B",
                    "Clinical Assistant Professor of B",    "B",
                                     "Email3@email.edu",    "B",
                                                     NA,    "B",
                                              "labcoat",    "B",
                                         "Person 4, MD",    "B",
                                       "Professor of B",    "B",
                                       "Professor of B",    "B",
                                     "Email4@email.edu",    "B",
                                                     NA,    "B",
                                         "Person 5, MD",    "C",
                                             "Person 5",    "C",
                                       "Professor of C",    "C",
                                       "Professor of C",    "C",
                             "Associate Chair, Quality",    "C",
              "Department of Urology and Service Chief",    "C",
                                     "Email5@email.edu",    "C",
                                         "132-547-1321",    "C",
                                                     NA,    "C"
  )


Which of the rows identify positions? Which ones field of expertise?

Generally, if you want to turn this messy table into a more tidy one, you‘d need at least a few patterns that could be exploited programmatically, e.g. one person always has X rows, or a new person always starts after … or there are only X distinct job positions etc.

@deschen
Thank you for your comment. position is like Professor of C and Associate Chair, Quality.
One pattern that recurs throughout the data is that each persons are separated by NAs.

How do you identify which position, email, name etc belong together? Based on what you’ve given us, you don’t seem to have enough information to do that.

“  One pattern that recurs throughout the data is that each persons are separated by NAs”: that is a critical piece of information that should be part of your question.

That‘s still not enough information, though. Regarding the positions: is there a fixed set of possible positions? Does the person row always has "…, MD" at the end? Any other potential rules? If you don‘t have such kind of rules, you probably need to accept the fact that this table is going to be very difficult to be turned into a tidy table and that you might be faster (depending on the number of people in your data) by manually reshaping the table in e.g. Excel.

Answered before your comment regarding each person being separated by NA so it does not retain any rows after an email address (but you implied this was not important in your question anyway). Here's a stepwise approach. Highlight up to each pipe "|>" and run to see how each step works. Comment below if you need further explanation.
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

df_wide <- df |>
  mutate(names = case_when(str_detect(data, ", MD$") ~ "name",
                           str_detect(data, "@") ~ "email",
                           .default = NA),
         data = str_remove(data, ", MD$"),
         tmp_start = cumsum(!is.na(names) & names == "name"),
         tmp_end = lag(cumsum(!is.na(names) & names == "email"), default = 0),
         id = if_else(tmp_start == tmp_end, NA, tmp_start)) |>
  group_by(id) |>
  fill(id, .direction = "downup") |>
  select(-starts_with("tmp")) |>
  filter(!is.na(id)) |>
  filter(!duplicated(data, fromFirst = TRUE)) |>
  mutate(names = if_else(is.na(names), paste0("position", 1:n() - 1), names)) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = names,
              values_from = data) |>
  ungroup() |>
  select(-id)

data.frame(df_wide)
# field     name                         position1                                           position2                               position3               position4         position5             position6            email
#     A Person 1          Associate Professor of A                                Program Associate, A Senior Medical Director, FGP Operations UMMG Ambulatory Surgery Residency Program Core Educational Lead Email1@email.edu
#     B Person 2 Clinical Assistant Professor of B Medical Student Clerkship and Core Educational Lead                                    <NA>                    <NA>              <NA>                  <NA> Email2@email.edu
#     B Person 3 Clinical Assistant Professor of B                                                <NA>                                    <NA>                    <NA>              <NA>                  <NA> Email3@email.edu
#     B Person 4                    Professor of B                                                <NA>                                    <NA>                    <NA>              <NA>                  <NA> Email4@email.edu
#     C Person 5                    Professor of C                            Associate Chair, Quality Department of Urology and Service Chief                    <NA>              <NA>                  <NA> Email5@email.edu

